# 'DispatcherUnhandledException' could not be found?

Tags: .net, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am currently having an issue concerning the `DispatcherUnhandledException`. I have checked with Google, but nobody else seems to have/have had this problem.

The issue is that Visual Studio throws error messages when I try to use the Dispatcher in App.xaml. My code looks like this:

```
<Application
    x:Class="TaskTree_Universal.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TaskTree_Universal"
    DispatcherUnhandledException="App_DispatcherUnhandledException"
    <!--The above line causes the problem-->
    RequestedTheme="Light">
</Application>
```

I do not quite understand why this causes the following error message to show:

> Error Unknown member 'DispatcherUnhandledException' on element 'Application'   >TaskTree_Universal C:...\TaskTree_Universal\TaskTree_Universal\App.xaml   6

And this message as well:

> Error The property 'DispatcherUnhandledException' was not found in type >'Application'. TaskTree_Universal >C:...\TaskTree_Universal\TaskTree_Universal\App.xaml  6

Since nobody else seems to have a solution to the problem of the Dispatcher simply not existing, I would be thankful for any help you have to offer. If any more information is neceassary to give an answer, then comment and I would be happy to share.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a UWP app you would add a handler for the [`Unhandled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception.aspx) event, instead of the [`DispatcherUnhandledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event in WPF:

```
<Application ...
    UnhandledException="Application_UnhandledException"
    RequestedTheme="Light">
</Application>
```

Comment: I read up on the Unhandled event, but I thought they were different. Thanks for clearing this up!